Need solana developer that can vouch for my project
I’m an Artist and starting my collection on Solana, but I have a problem I am in need of a reputable solana developer that can vouch for my project to Phantom. Trying to get them to remove some security messages on a claim function. Can you pls recommend someone that can help me or point me in the right direction
Here was Phantom supports message:
If you're unestablished or an anonymous dev team, please have someone established in  Solana dev community(not influencers) reach out to us (via email or blowfishxyz on Twitter) to vouch for you.
